# How to wait for a callback without blocking main thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I need to use a WebView in a custom renderer for Android and need to get a Value with EvaluateJavascript:

```
class ValueCallback : Java.Lang.Object, IValueCallback
{
    public Java.Lang.Object Value
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void OnReceiveValue(Java.Lang.Object value)
    {
        Value = value;
    }
}
```

This is called from a Method in the Renderer, which in Turn gets called from a Property like Duration

```
public double Duration;
```

Get Duration from Webview:

```
var callback = new ValueCallback();
View.EvaluateJavascript(jsToExecute, callback);
//How to wait here without blocking the MainThread?
```

The Problem is that EvaluateJavascript can only be called from the MainThread
and the Property is also called from MainThread.
So when I use something like AutoResetEvent to wait for the Script to finish, the result is a Deadlock.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking how to block the main thread without blocking the main thread.  The answer is quite simple, *you can't*.

If you don't want to block the main thread you're going to need to *not wait*, and instead do whatever you want to have happen after the callback executes *in the callback* rather than waiting for it.